# Wordpress Send Form Data on Redirection in Contact Form 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms

I'm using the popular wordpress plugin called Contact Form 7. Its easy to redirect the form after submitting to any page by adding this code `on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://example.com/';"`, but it does not carry the form values entered over, because its an AJAX submit.

The sites directions says `The simplest way is using on_sent_ok JavaScript action hook. By using this hook, you can specify a JavaScript code that you wish to run after the form is successfully submitted. You will find the Additional Settings field at the bottom of the contact form management page."

Would anyone be able to help or explain how I could carry the form values over on the redirect?

This is the redirection page I got from Contact Form 7

http://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/

Comment: I believe what you have is just for redirecting after a successful form submission. I believe you need to attach your form data to an object on the hook. I thought this site helped http://contactform7.com/tracking-form-submissions-with-google-analytics/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use this hook:

```
on_sent_ok: "location = 'https://gettinmobile.com/my-account/checkout/?level=1&' + $('form.wpcf7-form').serialize();"
```

This will append all the form data as parameters in the query string.

Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Answer (score 0):

The `on_sent_ok` is being phased out.

> Note: The method using `on_sent_ok` hook is no longer recommended.
>   This function is scheduled to be abolished by the end of 2017.
>
> https://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions

Comment: What is the recommended alternative to `on_sent_ok`?

Comment: Add a listener<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    location = 'http://example.com/';
}, false );
</script>

Comment: For myself I am trying another plugin that sends the output to a different url via a POST, using **Forms: 3rd-Party Integration** by Zaus.  If you are only concerned about capturing Google Analytics you could just add inside this listener an Event tracker call: `ga('send', 'event', 'Forms', 'contact');` instead of the `location` redirect.

Answer (score 0):

This is the new way to redirect contact form 7 on submission. Place in functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'redirect_cf7' );
   function redirect_cf7() {
   ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
         location = 'https://www.example.com/thank-you/';}, false );
      </script>
   <?php
}
```

NOTE: This will redirect all contact form 7 submission to that thank you page

Answer (score 0):

To add a 'redirection' function in the Contact Forms 7 you can just use the free plug-in: [Redirection for Contact Form 7 by Qube One](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/wpcf7-redirect/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.