# Send specific field data on redirection - Contact Form 7 Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I saw a previous answer by Edgar Villegas Alvarado which puts all the form data in the url:

```
on_sent_ok: "location = 'https://.../?level=1&' + $('form.wpcf7-form').serialize();"
```

This was very useful, however, I can't work out how to send a specific field(s) eg `email`. I thought a simple `?email` would do it, but it didn't worked.

Comment: In your question, can you link to the previous answer you're referring to?

Comment: @busse I think he's reffering to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25320279/wordpress-send-form-data-on-redirection-in-contact-form-7/25321226#25321226)

Comment: You should have your email field in the serialized data, `$('form.wpcf7-form').serialize()` serialize all the form inputs.

Answer (score 0):

1. Assign a ID to the input you want to send.
2. Then change the actual code to this one:

```
on_sent_ok: "location = 'https://example.com/other-page/?email=' + jQuery('form.wpcf7-form #assigned_id').val();"
```